# Linkedin api post not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4

public ActionResult AuthorizeLinkedin(string code, string state, string error, string error_description)
{
    //Linkedin
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(error_description))
    {
        // handle error and error_description
    }
    else
    {
        objusermodel = new UserModel();
        var host = ExtractHost();
        var _redirectUrl = Url.Action("AuthorizeLinkedin", "Investments", null, Request.Url.Scheme, host);
        var userToken = api.OAuth2.GetAccessToken(code, _redirectUrl);
        // keep this token for your API requests
        var user = new UserAuthorization(userToken.AccessToken);
        var fields = FieldSelector.For().WithFirstName().WithFollowing();
        if (Session["ShareResponse"] != null)
        {
            shareResponse = Session.GetObjectFromJson("ShareResponse");
        }
        //try
        //{

```
    var profile = api.Profiles.GetMyProfile(user, new string[] { "en-US" }, fields);
    api.Social.Post(user, new PostShare()
    {
        Content = new PostShareContent()
        {
            Title = "FUNDING PORTAL",
            Description = shareResponse.Message,
            SubmittedUrl = shareResponse.ShareUrl,
            SubmittedImageUrl = shareResponse.ImageUrl,
        },
        Visibility = new Visibility()
        {
            Code = "anyone"

        },
    });

    shareResponse.Success = 1;
    shareResponse.flag = true;
    Session.SetObjectAsJson("ShareResponse", shareResponse);
    TempData["PromoboxFN"] = shareResponse.ImageUrl;
    TempData.Keep("PromoboxFN");
    return Redirect(shareResponse.RedirectUrl);
    //}
    //catch (Exception ex)
    //{
    //    throw;
    //    shareResponse.Success = 0;
    //    shareResponse.flag = true;
    //    Session.SetObjectAsJson("ShareResponse", shareResponse);
    //    return Redirect(shareResponse.RedirectUrl);
    //}

}
return null;
```

}

Give the error:

> "api.Social.Post(user, new PostShare()" to this point An exception of
>   type 'Sparkle.LinkedInNET.LinkedInApiException' occurred in
>   Sparkle.LinkedInNET.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: API error (500) Internal service error at https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

Comment: `An exception of type 'Sparkle.LinkedInNET.LinkedInApiException' occurred in Sparkle.LinkedInNET.dll but was not handled in user code` coupled with your commented out `catch` statement means you have no idea what the problem is. Uncomment your catch block, catch a `LinkInApiException` and see what it's telling you.

Comment: I use try catch and get error like :API error (500) Internal service error at https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

Comment: Have you looked at what a 500 internal error is? It's server side, meaning the API is having issues....